# Why do characters get removed from a textbox when I type into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing a jQuery code on the MVC view to count down the characters entered in a textbox. For example, if the textbox has a limit of 100 and I type "a", then I get a notice below a textbox saying "99", the number decrements as I type. This works fine for my first two textboxes, but on the third textbox, when I type, the character gets removed. Below is the code. Can you please point me to the right direction? What is it that I am not doing right?

The scripts:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        // Character count down for Project Name
        function countChar(val) {
            var len = val.value.length;
            var maxLength = document.getElementById(val.id).maxLength;
            
            if (len >= maxLength) {
                val.value = val.value.substring(0, maxLength);
            } else {
                $("#charNum").text(maxLength - len);
            }
        };

        // Character count down for Nearest Town
        function nearestTownChars(val) {
            var len = val.value.length;
            var maxLength = document.getElementById(val.id).maxLength;
            
            if (len >= maxLength) {
                val.value = val.value.substring(0, maxLength);
            } else {
                $("#nearestTown").text(maxLength - len);
            }
        }

        // Character count down for Description
        function descriptionChars(val) {
            var len = val.value.length;
            var maxLength = document.getElementById(val.id).maxLength;
            
            if (len >= maxLength) {
                val.value = val.value.substring(0, maxLength);
            }
            else {
                $("#descriptionCharNum").text(maxLength - len);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The code for the nearest town textbox, it works:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.NearestTown, new { @title = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.ProjectDetail.NearestTown, ViewData).Description, @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @style = "text-align:left" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.NearestTown, new { @class = "form-control lockable1", onkeyup = "nearestTownChars(this)"}) 
                    <div id="nearestTown"></div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.NearestTown, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectDetail.WardId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @style = "text-align:left" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectDetail.WardId, new SelectList(ViewBag.WardList, "Value", "Text"), new { ID = "Ward", @class = "form-control lockable2" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.WardId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

The code for ProjectDetail name, it works:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.Name, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label required", @style = "text-align:left" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.Name, new { @class = "form-control lockable1", @id = "projectname", @required = "required", onkeyup = "countChar(this)" })
                        <div id="charNum"></div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The description textbox, it does not work, instead when I type the characters get removed:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.Description, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @style = "text-align:left" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.Description, new { @class = "form-control lockable1", onkeyup = "descriptionChars(this)" })
                        <div id="descriptionCharNum"></div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ProjectDetail.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please assist, thank you so kind.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need three functions doing the same work for you. You can reuse the code just passing the ID of the element you want to calculate as a parameter.

Your code is the same in the three functions, therefore you are probably setting the values on the 3rd function wrong. Press F12 in your browser, go to the console and see if you're getting some errors.

this line is key to your function

```
var maxLength = document.getElementById(val.id).maxLength;
```

check if the correct value is getting into it or set it to your max length and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Fernando. One question though, how would I reuse the code and passing the ID of the element in this case?

Comment: You're welcome! You can change on your else the hard coded ID in every function for the ID that are you getting as parameter. Example: $("#descriptionCharNum").text(maxLength - len) for $(val.id).text(maxLength - len);

Changing this you'll see that the three function will be exactly the same, so, you can use the same on the three places. charCount is a good name.